# socket.io) Is it okay to show port numbers in client side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm kinda new to socket.io and node.js.

I currently set up my server with nginx as reverse proxy.

Regular requests are going to port 8080, apache server.

Some specific requests will go to port 8888, node.js server.

I created a simple chat using socket.io and node.js.

Everything works fine, but since node.js server is listening to port 8888..

I have codes on client as

```
<script src='myserver:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

and

```
var socket = io.connect('myserver:8888');
```

Is it okay to write like that?

Or is there any other way I can prevent writing port numbers directly?

Comment: I have not used nginx but just trying to help, client side can read a config file from server [may be in AJAX request] and then crate a socket connection. This will keep the port number hidden from client until he goes into console to look at it. And even you can use different port internally in node.js [using different node process]. so that port given to client will be only accepting request. and then use different port+process[hidden from client] to run your business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to proxy request using nginx to you node.js server. That way you can have your code on client as

```
<script src='node.myserver/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

instead of having to write port number.

look in to this tutorial

https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/

Comment: Page is rendered by apache+php, and chat room app is going to communicate with node.js server. So the request to node.js server is sent from myserver/phppage. That's why I was stuck. I didn't think about using subdomain for node.js server. I will try that thanks!